# 64-bit Password Hashes in MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, hash, database-schema

I use this function for hashing my passwords:

```
// RETURNS: rAyZOnlNBxO2WA53z2rAtFlhdS+M7kec9hskSCpeL6j+WwcuUvfFbpFJUtHvv7ji   
base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha384', $str . SC_NONCE, SC_SITEKEY, true));
```

And I store hashes in **char(64)** field (MySQL -InnoDB).

Should I use **varchar(64)** instead of *char(64)*? Why?

**Edit:**
I changed *sha256* with *sha384*. Because in this example, sha256 always returns 44 bytes for me. Sorry for confusing. Now it's 64-bytes.

Comment: Is it definitely the case the a base 64 encoded string returns a hash of 64 bits in length? I didn't think it did...

Comment: @BrendanBullen - I updated question. Sorry for the confusing example :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

varchars save storage by only using up to the length required.  If the 64 bit hash is always 64 then it makes no difference in terms of storage so probably char is just as good as varchar in this case.

If you have variable length data to store, then a varchar will save wasting unnecessary space.

Comment: Well, you actually use 1 byte overhead with varchar compared to char, how much difference that makes is another story :)

Answer (score 5):

You should use CHAR(64) since your hash is fixed in length. Using VARCHAR will add another byte, wasting space.

Comment: Is it definitely a fixed length?

Answer (score 2):

Even though you are using a Base 64 encoded string, the result is not necessarily 64 bits in length. In this case, `VARCHAR` is better because the result can be shorter than 64 bits.

In fact as seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table), 64 bits is the maximum length rather than the set length.